# Can Spark ForEachPartitionAsync be async on worker nodes?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, asynchronous

I write a custom spark sink. In my `addBatch` method I use `ForEachPartitionAsync` which if I'm not wrong only makes the driver work asynchronously, returning a future.

```
    val work: FutureAction[Unit] = rdd.foreachPartitionAsync { rows =>
       val sourceInfo: StreamSourceInfo = serializeRowsAsInputStream(schema, rows)

       val ackIngestion = Future {
       ingestRows(sourceInfo) } andThen {
       case Success(ingestion) => ackIngestionDone(partitionId, ingestion)
       }

       Await.result(ackIngestion, timeOut) // I would like to remove this line..
    }
    work onSuccess {
      case _ => // move data from temporary table, report success of all workers
   }
        work onFailure{
      //delete tmp data
      case t => throw t.getCause
    }
```

I can't find a way to run the worker nodes without blocking on the Await call, as if I remove them a success is reported to the `work` future object although the future didn't really finish.

> Is there a way to report to the driver that all the workers finished
>   their asynchronous jobs?

Note: I looked at the `foreachPartitionAsync` function and it has only one implementation that expects a function that returns a Unit (i would've expected it to have another one returning a future or maybe a CountDownLatch..)

Comment: Not sure I understand why you would do this....

Comment: If all code is async the process runs faster .. the Await line makes it non-async

Comment: Correction: Right u r. That said, Executors must be available and all is distributed anyway - albeit that multiple partitions can be on the same Worker. I doubt it is worth the fuss in any event as I see the experts have not responded. I would rely on more resources and sharing of resources.

Comment: The fact that experts did not respond may suggest that spark doesn't support it not that this shouldn't be ..

Comment: Try it out and reveal to us. For files processing and such I get the use case, for sure. Success.

Comment: @hebluephantom try what out? foreachPartitionAsync works it just not what i want... as i said it only makes the driver work asynchronously but it doesn't expect the worker to be async

Comment: also fine, success, the answer your own question or obviate it

Comment: @hebluephantom you didn't understand the question then.. i ask about a way to make the workers part async as it is now blocking on the Await.result call

Comment: I guess I am not so smart